# Changing the default activity at runtime

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I have 2 activities : `intro_activity` and `main_activity`.

At the first touch with the app, the user must complete some details in `intro_activity` which are being saved with Shared Preferences.

I put the `intro_activity` as default, but is there any way to change `main_activity` to default if the user already completed the details on `intro_activity`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check in the intro_activity if the details are completed and then you can "redirect" the user to main_activity by creating a new Intent and starting a new activity.

Answer (score 0):

Use different activity like `Splash` and make your logic there. Every time app is launching via Splash activity So you can redirect to any activity according to your `shared_preferences` value.